# Possible to prevent AdMob Video AD closed by user before video finish?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

As titled, is it possible?  I have been trying to google, but I don't see any answer.

Far as I know, if that's a video AD, its will have a count down for 5 seconds until User is able to close the AD.

I don't think is best practice to prevent user to close to AD until Video finish, but is my task to find it out...

Comment: Not doable. Google doesn't allow developers to control whether a user chooses to skip the ad or not. If you absolutely want something like that, use a rewarded video ad unit from a different ad provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have control over this.
And not all video ads have the count down timer.

Comment: So far I only seen video with 5 sec count down timer.  How will be the video ads without count down timer look like?  When the video show, user can just click the 'X' and closer instantly?